Dynamically size chart to fit within window
I'm using Chart.js to display charts. It's working well. I've decided to add a full-screen feature, which opens up the chart in a full-screen modal popup.
I have this working, but the chart takes the available width and sizes the chart accordingly. On most displays, this means the chart is too tall for the screen and must be scrolled vertically.
Is there a way to size the chart to ensure it fits (both width and height) entirely within the parent element? This would need to occur dynamically because it would need to be resized every time the user resizes the browser window.

Have you set maintainAspectRatio: false option?

@kikon: Is there a way to do that from code?

Yes, all options can be set dynamically, see updating charts, but I can't imagine why would  that be necessary, maybe you should post something about your environment.
